# How to vertically center a paragraph around a specific word?

Tags: html, css

I have a paragraph within a div. I would like the paragraph to be positioned such that a specific word of the paragraph is centered vertically. I have tried unsuccessfully to do this with a span. Is there any simple way to do this?

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: relative;
}

span {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;

}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <span>blah</span> blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
</div>
```

[image: Result]
[image: Desired result]

Comment: Basically no. You will need javascript

Answer (score -2):

To vertically center a specific word within a paragraph inside a div, you can use a  CSS  transformations. Here's how you can achieve this:

```
div {
width: 300px;
height: 250px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
position: relative;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

}

```
 span {
font-weight: bold;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
transform: translateY(0%);
```

}